# C# SQL adding items in gallerycontrol/listview are multiplying

Tags: c#, sql, listview, devexpress

I'm sorry if my title is wrong because I don't know what exactly the title should be.

So my program's algorithm is when every time the textbox changes , it will retrieve some data in the database and it will add into the DEVEXPRESS's gallery control

By the way here is my problem, so I have a textbox for searching and a devexpress's gallery control. Sometimes the items that has been added in the gallery control are multiplying and sometimes they are not.

I don't know what it is happening.

Check out my code:

```
 private void searchControl1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchControl1.Text))
        {

            group.Items.Clear();

            ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(searchMyData);
            Thread t = new Thread(pts);
            t.Start(searchControl1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(LoadBooks);
            Thread t = new Thread(pts);
            t.Start();
        }
    }

    public void searchMyData(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            string text = state.ToString();
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from booktable where booktitle like'" + text + "%' OR bookauthor like'" + text + "%' ";


                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from booktable where Match(booktitle) Against(@names IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR Match(bookauthor) Against(@names IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@names", text.ToString()+"*".ToString());
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", text.ToString() + "*".ToString());
                MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                adap.Fill(ds);
                DataView dv = new DataView();
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        byte[] byteBLOBData = (byte[])ds.Rows[i]["bookphoto"];
                        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);

                        Image bookimages = Image.FromStream(stream);
                        string author = ds.Rows[i]["bookauthor"].ToString();
                        string title = ds.Rows[i]["booktitle"].ToString();

                        //Add Books in the Gallery Control for every text changed 
                        group.Items.Add(new GalleryItem(bookimages, title, author));
                        group.Items[i].HoverImage = group.Items[i].Image;

                    }
                }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you add the same item several times in the searchMyData method. Clear existing items before adding new ones. group.Items.Clear()

Comment: Didn't I already clear the items in my if statement in the searcontrol method?

Comment: Yes, I see it in the searchControl1_TextChanged event handler. But, then you execute the searchMyData method in another thread. The method will be executed asynchronously. So, it's possible that the searchControl1_TextChanged event handler is raised twice, but the searchMyData method invoked by the first firing is not yet executed. As a result, you clear items twice in a row and only then, you populate them. I'd suggest you clear items in searchMyData. Plus, add a locker so that two threads don't modify items at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to avoid conflict between threads.

```
object lockObject = new object();

private void searchControl1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchControl1.Text))
        {

            group.Items.Clear();

            ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(searchMyData);
            Thread t = new Thread(pts);
            t.Start(searchControl1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(LoadBooks);
            Thread t = new Thread(pts);
            t.Start();
        }
    }
}

//You also must implement this technic on LoadBooks

public void LoadBooks()
{
     try{} catch{}
    finally
    {
         // Check if searchControl1.Text changed during the time this method execute. If changed, call this function again, pass new string.
         Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}

public void searchMyData(object state)
{
    string text = state.ToString();
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from booktable where booktitle like'" + text + "%' OR bookauthor like'" + text + "%' ";


            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from booktable where Match(booktitle) Against(@names IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR Match(bookauthor) Against(@names IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@names", text.ToString()+"*".ToString());
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", text.ToString() + "*".ToString());
            MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            DataView dv = new DataView();
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    byte[] byteBLOBData = (byte[])ds.Rows[i]["bookphoto"];
                    var stream = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);

                    Image bookimages = Image.FromStream(stream);
                    string author = ds.Rows[i]["bookauthor"].ToString();
                    string title = ds.Rows[i]["booktitle"].ToString();

                    //Add Books in the Gallery Control for every text changed 
                    group.Items.Add(new GalleryItem(bookimages, title, author));
                    group.Items[i].HoverImage = group.Items[i].Image;

                }
            }));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
         // Check if searchControl1.Text changed during the time this method execute. If changed, call this function again, pass new string.
         Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am having an error after I've added the Monitor object in my Loadbook method , there error was Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

Comment: Can you post your `Loadbook` function also?